# Snowflake, can I assign a role that just allows access to billing from Accountadmin role

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are currently running a payg snowflake account with a credit card for billing. This is controlled by a Finance user and ideally I would like to restrict this user to just billing and card application of the accountadmin role, rather than opening up the other operational powers of that role.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have ACCOUNTADMIN role to be able to change credit card information:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-trial-account.html#adding-a-credit-card-to-a-trial-account

If all you need is to monitor usage and billing history, you can grant MONITOR USAGE to the role:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-configure.html#label-allow-other-users-to-monitor-usage-billing-history

Comment: Ok so what you are saying is the Only ACCOUNTADMIN role with full privileges can add credit card info.